# Jackson Serialize Object is empty in Java WS

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO:

```
public class Step implements IStep {
    String identifier;
    ApprovalAction action;
    Approver approver;
    Asset asset;
    Outcome decision;
    Actor requestedFor;

    //...
}
```

I have a web service method:

```
Step step = new BasicApprovalStep(
    new ApprovalAction("Name Test", "Description Test", "Instructions Test"), 
    mockAssetService.getRandomItem(),
    mockActorService.getRandomItem());

GenericEntity< Collection<Step> > entity = new GenericEntity<Collection<Step>>(Arrays.asList(new Step[]{step})) {};

System.err.println("Returning " + step + " " + step.getIdentifier() + " " + step.getRequestedFor() + " " + step.getAsset());
return Response.ok(entity).build();
```

It has these annotations:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

I always get `[{}]` as the response to my REST call.  I see the print statements so I know the thing is returning data:

> > Returning BasicApprovalStep@20d36037 7bde8abd-3632-47ce-98a3-d1ddafe875a1 entities.Actor@19011a5d entities.Asset@442102c

Why is this not working, I'm the same pattern (returning Result like this) with other services (Approver, Actor, and so on) and it works great?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have @Produces("application/json") annotation on your API method?

Comment: I have these: ` @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: Do you have any getter defined in the class? Why do you return a GenericEntity<Collection<Step>>, and not simply a Collection<Step>?

Comment: The log output that you are using to verify the data is accessing the `step` instance, but you are actually returning the `entity` instance. Have you confirmed that `entity` is constructed correctly and that it contains what you expect?

Comment: When I print entity.getEntity() I see: `.entities.BasicApprovalStep@13461dc2]`  Which is correct